# Mock return a list based on parameters

Tags: java, mocking, mockito

I'm trying to mock a request using a List of String and create an List of objects using parameter passed... something like:

```
        when(tagDao.findByNameInOrderByName(Matchers.anyListOf(String.class))).thenReturn(new ArrayList<Tag>() {
        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 8227782193263533677L;
        {
            add(new Tag("name"));
            add(new Tag("surname"));
        }
    });
```

I've tried something like

```
        when(tagDao.findByNameInOrderByName(Matchers.anyListOf(String.class))).thenReturn(new Answer<List<Tag>>() {
        @Override
        public List<Tag> answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
            // Object[] args = invocation.getArguments();
            List<Tag> tags = new ArrayList<Tag>();
            return tags;
        }
    });
```

And I got the following error:
the method thenReturn(List) in the type OngoingStubbing> is not applicable for the arguments( new Answer>() {})

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should use `thenAnswer` instead of `thenReturn`

```
when(tagDao.findByNameInOrderByName(Matchers.anyListOf(String.class))).thenAnswer(new Answer<List<Tag>>() {
            @Override
            public List<Tag> answer(InvocationOnMock invocationOnMock) throws Throwable {
                Object[] args = invocationOnMock.getArguments();
                List<Tag> tags = new ArrayList<Tag>();
                return tags;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you looking you looking for a technical solution ... to a problem that should be solved in a different way.

What you have: some method is invoked by your code under test, passing a List of values. And now you want to *somehow* return a result build "around" those incoming values. The other answer tells you how to get there (where I would have looked to see if you can do that using an ArgumentCaptor).

But let's step back. Keep in mind that you write unit tests to test **one** specific aspect of the public contract of some method. But it seems that there will be **different** invocations of `findByNameInOrderByName()`. And now you are looking for a way to generate different return results for different input.

My suggestion is not **not** do this. Instead: clearly separate things into **different** testcases. Like in:

```
@Test
public void testXyzWithFooBar() {
  when(tagDao.findByNameInOrderByName(Arrays.asList("foo", "bar").thenReturn(Arrays.asList(x, y));
  ... call xyz ...

@Test
public void testXyzWithFooOnly() {
  when(tagDao.findByNameInOrderByName(Arrays.asList("foo").thenReturn(Arrays.asList(z, b));
  ... call xyz ...
```

In other words: I would rather strive to avoid the additional complexity of having a mock object return something *implicitly* based on input parameters.

Instead: clearly express the expected cases **explicitly**. This also leads to *stricter* tests. Your idea means: *anything* can go to that mocked method call. My version *clearly* states what you expect to happen.